# C#, return a string from a function that calls another async function?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I want to return a string from a function that calls another async function. Can you tell me if this is possible?
This is my function

```
public async Task<TokenCredential> LoginAsync()
{
    var credential = await GenerateCredentialAsync(); // This is a library function 
                                                   //that returns a 'Task<TokenCredential>'

    return credential.Token; // I want to return this value which is a string
}
```

I only want to return the token value. But if I change the return type. I get a compiler error

> "The await operator can only be used within an async method"

.

If I remove await altogether like below:

```
public string LoginAsync()
{
    var credential = GenerateCredentialAsync();            
    return credential.Token;
}
```

I get this error when trying to dereference credential.token

> 'Task< TokenCredential > does not contain a definition for Token.

Can you please help with this?

Comment: What type is `Token`? Your first version will work if you `return async Task<tokentype>` instead of `Task<TokenCredential>`.

Comment: Not much of the above makes sense, your method is marked with `async` but you say you get an error from using `await`, there's also no anonymous classes or code above.

Comment: What is the actual question here, you cannot return *just* the token value from an async method, you must return a task that will eventually contain the token, thus the return type of `Task<T>`. You *have* to use this return type (or `void`) when using `async`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't try to wrap an asynchronous method in a synchronous wrapper if you don't know what you're doing, this will invariably lead to problems such as deadlocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return type of your method should actually be `Task<TokenCredential>` provided that that the `Token` property of the credential returns a `TokenCredential`. If the Token property returns a `string` the return type of the method should be `Task<string>`. So far so good.

The issue is probably how you call the `LoginAsync()` method. Since this is an *asynchronous* you should await it:

```
TokenCredential token = await LoginAsync();
```

This requires you to call it from a method that is marked as `async`.

If you define the `LoginAsync` method as a synchronous method you need to get the result of the `GenerateCredentialAsync()` before you return from the LoginAsync() method. You can do this by blocking on the `Result` property of the returned `Task`:

```
public string LoginAsync()
{
    var credential = GenerateCredentialAsync().Result;            
    return credential.Token;
}
```

Note that this latter approach is not recommended though.  Please refer to Stephen Cleary's blog post for more information about why you shouldn't block on async code: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing an async declaration somewhere.

Your above code:

```
public async Task<TokenCredential> LoginAsync()
{
    var credential = await GenerateCredentialAsync(); // This is a library function that returns a 'Task<TokenCredential>'

    return credential.Token; // I want to return this value which is a string
}
```

Is 100% correct (assuming that GenerateCredentialAsync contains a property 'Token' that returns a 'TokenCredential'

The problem you are likely having is that whatever calls LoginAsync is missing an 'async' declaration.

**You cannot 'await' something unless you are in a method marked as async**

A general rule is you will need every method in the 'chain' to be marked as async.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the type of TokenCredential.Token as the return type in Task<>.

If the TokenCredential.Token is of string type, you should have:

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync()
```

Regards